# Is the version of Windows 7 that is currently available any different from that which will be released on October 23?

Tags: windows-7

As is common knowledge now, Windows 7 RTM is available for download if you're a MSDN subscriber.

The question is - will this version of Windows 7 be any different from the one that will be officially launched on the 23rd of October this year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS have said the MSDN (and technet) version is the Retail version (or VL for Enterprise Ed.) that will be available on the shelf in October.

That doesn't mean that OEMs won't incorporate patches (like those released yesterday) into the base build.